# Emacs and xft fonts

Tags: fonts, emacs

I'm trying to set up `Consolas` font in `emacs`. I built emacs with `--configure --with-xft` and put:

```
Emacs.font: Consolas-16
Emacs.fontBackend: xf
```

to the `.xsession`

But when I'm trying to start emacs I'm getting this error:

```
Font `Consolas-16' is not defined
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential texinfo libx11-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgtk2.0-dev libncurses-dev
./configure --with-dbus --with-toolkit-scroll-bars --with-xft --with-xpm --with-jpeg --with-tiff --with-gif --with-libotf --with-xim --with-gconf --with-gnutls
```

Comment: Where did you get those dependencies and how did you know to pass configure those arguments?

Comment: See `./configure --help`

Comment: Before see this answer, i got `Font ‘Inconsolata-15’ is not defined` error when compile emacs 26.1, after install `libgtk2.0-dev` and recompile, fixed. Thanks